# How To Shorten This SQL Query Without A Million AND/OR's?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 13 columns (one is for the row ID # and the other 12 represent one for each month of the year).  Each column will only contain numbers and I want to write several queries to check each row for certain conditions and return the ID of any rows that match.

So far I've been fine with writing all the basic SELECT queries but now I'm getting a bit stuck on writing SELECT queries to check multiple conditions at once without writing a million lines of code each time.

The current query I'm writing needs to check each pair of consecutive months (e.g. Jan/Feb, Feb/Mar, etc) to see how big the difference is between them and it needs to return any rows where 2 lots of consecutive months have a > 20% difference between them and the remaining pairs are all < 10% difference.

For example, if January was 1000 and February was 1300, that's a 30% difference so that's 1 lot.  Then if say April was 1500 and May was 2100, that's a 40% difference so there's the 2nd lot.  Then as long as every other pair (Feb/Mar, Mar/Apr, ..., Nov/Dec) are all < 10% difference each, then that row needs to be returned.

Unfortunately, the only way I can get this to work is by manually checking every single possibility (which works) but isn't very re-useable for writing similar queries.

Here is an abbreviated version of what I've got so far:

```
SELECT pkID
FROM dbo.tblMonthData
WHERE

((colFeb > colJan * 1.2 AND colMar > colFeb * 1.2) AND (colApr < colMar * 1.1 AND colMay < colApr * 1.1 AND colJun < colMay * 1.1 AND colJul < colJun * 1.1 AND colAug < colJul * 1.1 AND colSep < colAug * 1.1 AND colOct < colSep * 1.1 AND colNov < colOct * 1.1 AND colDec < colNov * 1.1))

OR ((colFeb > colJan * 1.2 AND colApr > colMar * 1.2) AND (colMar < colFeb * 1.1 AND colMay < colApr * 1.1 AND colJun < colMay * 1.1 AND colJul < colJun * 1.1 AND colAug < colJul * 1.1 AND colSep < colAug * 1.1 AND colOct < colSep * 1.1 AND colNov < colOct * 1.1 AND colDec < colNov * 1.1))

OR ((colFeb > colJan * 1.2 AND colMay > colApr * 1.2) AND (colMar < colFeb * 1.1 AND colApr < colMar * 1.1 AND colJun < colMay * 1.1 AND colJul < colJun * 1.1 AND colAug < colJul * 1.1 AND colSep < colAug * 1.1 AND colOct < colSep * 1.1 AND colNov < colOct * 1.1 AND colDec < colNov * 1.1))

...

OR ((colNov > colOct * 1.2 AND colDec > colNov * 1.2) AND (colFeb < colJan * 1.1 AND colMar < colFeb * 1.1 AND colApr < colMar * 1.1 AND colMay < colApr * 1.1 AND colJun < colMay * 1.1 AND colJul < colJun * 1.1 AND colAug < colJul * 1.1 AND colSep < colAug * 1.1 AND colOct < colSep * 1.1))
```

In total there is about 55 lines of OR statements to check every possible combination of this.  If I then went to query something similar (e.g. return all Row ID #'s where 2 pairs are greater than 50% and 4 pairs are under 10%), that involves writing another long query from scratch checking every other possible combination.

So I was wondering how I could re-write this in a shorter version that could also be more re-useable for similar queries?

Comment: Is this 'table' a view constructed off of other tables? It is odd that you would have months as columns. The query would be a lot easier there were a month COLUMN, with each month as values on different rows. In that case you could use LAG/LEAD.

Comment: The design is clearly unnormalized. SQL doesn't work well for data designed like a spreadsheet. Do you have the option of changing to a proper relational database design? If not, this is only the beginning of your troubles.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys.  Brian, this is just a single table at the moment with all the data.  And dkretz, you are correct this was literally a spreadsheet that has been "copy and pasted" into SQL Server 2012.  I'm quickly learning the hard way that just because you can do that, doesn't always mean it's a good idea.  I will look into seeing if this can be changed to a proper database design for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as an alternate answer to @Pieter's answer and to illustrate how a simpler data structure may make your task easier, I suggest the following:

```
create view tblEasy as (
select pkID, 1 as colMonth, colJan as colValue from tblMonthData
UNION
select pkID, 2 as colMonth, colFeb as colValue from tblMonthData
UNION
select pkID, 3 as colMonth, colMar as colValue from tblMonthData
UNION
select pkID, 4 as colMonth, colApr as colValue from tblMonthData
UNION
select pkID, 5 as colMonth, colMay as colValue from tblMonthData
UNION
select pkID, 6 as colMonth, colJun as colValue from tblMonthData
UNION
select pkID, 7 as colMonth, colJul as colValue from tblMonthData
UNION
select pkID, 8 as colMonth, colAug as colValue from tblMonthData
UNION
select pkID, 9 as colMonth, colSep as colValue from tblMonthData
UNION
select pkID, 10 as colMonth, colOct as colValue from tblMonthData
UNION
select pkID, 11 as colMonth, colNov as colValue from tblMonthData
UNION
select pkID, 12 as colMonth, colDec as colValue from tblMonthData
);
```

This makes the view look like how I would have structured the table initially. Then it is easy to create the pairs by comparing the value on `colMonth` to that on `colMonth + 1`.

I made a fiddle to illustrate how the comparing could also be done in a view, and then the query itself if fairly obvious.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/600f6/4

Note that performance is not great due to the initial table structure.

---

**Update** 
Since this is being accepted as the answer, I will embed the extra details from the sqlfiddle.

Extra view to pre-calculate the difference between consecutive months:

```
create view tblPairs as (
  select t1.pkId , t1.colMonth as colStart, (t2.colValue * 100 / t1.colValue) as colPercentage
  from tblEasy as t1
  inner join tblEasy as t2 
  on t1.pkId = t2.pkId and t1.colMonth = t2.colMonth - 1);
```

Query to find where 2 months have over 20% increase and the other 9 have less than 10%:

```
select distinct pkid
from tblPairs as t1
where 2 = (
    select count(*)
    from tblPairs as t2
    where t2.pkid = t1.pkid
    and colPercentage >= 120)
and 9 = (
    select count(*)
    from tblPairs as t2
    where t2.pkid = t1.pkid
    and colPercentage <= 110)
;
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  This was the part I was missing.  Even after unpivoting the data I was still having issues figuring out how to query it properly.  Your idea of creating a custom View and your sample query solved it for me.  Unfortunately, running lots of comparisons on unpivoted views seems to be quite slow.  So I ended up inserting the view into a new, static table and am querying that directly.  Now my queries execute in a matter of seconds and I can easily use variations of your query/view layout to check multiple conditions quickly without re-writing millions of lines of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Unpivot the table to perform the comparison, and then if necessary pivot back to the original format.:

```
with 
unpvt as (
    select    
         YearNo     
        ,case MonthNo when  1 then colJan
                      when  2 then colFeb
                      when  3 then colMar
                      when  4 then colApr
                      when  5 then colMay
                      when  6 then colJun
                      when  7 then colJul
                      when  8 then colAug
                      when  9 then colSep
                      when 10 then colOct
                      when 11 then colNov
                      when 12 then colDec 
                              else 0
         end as Value
        ,YearNo * 12 + MonthNo - 1 as PeriodNo
        /* other columns */
--    from dbo.tblMonthData
    from tblMonthData
    cross join ( values
        (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
    )months(MonthNo)
)
select 
    this.*,
    this.Value - isnull(prev.Value,0) as Delta
from unpvt          this
left join unpvt     prev
   on prev.PeriodNo = this.PeriodNo - 1
;
```

etc. Depending on your version of SQL Server you may have access to the [UNPIVOT clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) to compress the source even further.

If you have a [static NUMBERS table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) then the first twelve rows from that can be used instead of the VALUE initialization in the CROSS JOIN.

Comment: not sure if this works but instead of repeatedly typing `MonthNo`, we can use the form `CASE MonthNo WHEN 1 THEN ... WHEN 2 THEN ...` for a shorter expression.

Comment: @KingKing: Thank you, I will edit - it is also possibly a more efficient construct from being eligible for implementation as a jump table. Not sure why I often forget about that variant.

Comment: My observation (on the problem, not this answer) would be that if you have to unpivot the table to access your data it indicates that the data should not have been stored that way in the first place. Instead, your table should have had three columns: `yearNum`, `monthNum`, `value`.

Comment: @Turophile: Of course - but we all will encounter times where it is necessary to work with un-normalized legacy data, and knowing how to do so efficiently is part and parcel of being a competent DB Developer (or DBA).

Comment: @Pieter: Thanks for your query but I'm not sure I'm following 100% sorry.  It seems I can't post code in comments so I'll try to explain as best as I can.  I like how you transposed my table and also your Delta column showing the difference between each pair of consecutive months.  However I'm still unsure how to query this without checking every condition like my original query?  For example, if I had one original row with pkID of 5 and each Delta was 100,100,300,100,600,100 for the rest...  how could I query this to return only pkID's where 2 Delta's >= 200 and all remaining Delta's <=100?

Comment: @Turophile: Also thanks for the tip that unpivoting data isn't ideal.  If there is a simple way to query what I want using it, I was going to start relying on unpivoting everything.  I've now realised that in the future, I should pay more attention to storing the data correctly before I worry about how to query it.  For now I'm likely stuck with it the way it is, so it will at least be useful to know how to work with it in less than ideal conditions.

Comment: @Pieter yes, the question and your answer are valid -  you have to work with what you have. And it could well be that the table is structured the way it is because most of the processing is easier that way. And pivoting/unpivoting data is a useful skill to have in your toolbox. But since this site is for learning (and many questions are from beginners) I like to point out wherever possible the root cause of the "problem" aka how to do it better/easier next time. It seems Calcolat has confirmed above that the approach could/should have been different, and will learn something, which is great.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot your data row by row in a cross apply using the [table valued constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) creating a derived table with two consecutive month values. Also in the cross apply you can do your calculations and counting rows that meet a specific criteria using a [case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) and [sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx).

Your query could look something like this.

```
select MD.pkID
from dbo.tblMonthData as MD
  cross apply (
              select sum(case when P.Mon1 * 1.2 < P.Mon2 then 1 end),
                     sum(case when P.Mon1 * 1.1 > P.Mon2 then 1 end)
              from (values(MD.colJan, MD.colFeb),
                          (MD.colFeb, MD.colMar),
                          (MD.colMar, MD.colApr),
                          (MD.colApr, MD.colMay),
                          (MD.colMay, MD.colJun),
                          (MD.colJun, MD.colJul),
                          (MD.colJul, MD.colAug),
                          (MD.colAug, MD.colSep),
                          (MD.colSep, MD.colOct),
                          (MD.colOct, MD.colNov),
                          (MD.colNov, MD.colDec)) as P(Mon1, Mon2)
              ) as C(MoreThan20, LessThan10)
where C.MoreThan20 = 2 and
      C.LessThan10 = 9
```